# menu without label wp

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a menu on wordpress using this

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order','menu_class' => 'navlink', 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'header-menu') ); ?>
```

the output is like this

```
<div class="navlink">
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item active"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/about/">About</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/skills/">Skills</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/project/">Project</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

now i want is to display my menu without the labels about, skills... is it possible? i tried using the menu and display it via widgets but the menu won't allow me to add pages without any labels. it automatically removes the page from the menu.

like this.

```
<li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item active"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/about/"></a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/skills/"></a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/project/"></a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/contact/"></a></li>
```

Is their any possible way other than using static html? I'm using foundationpress as my theme.

I will display the label of my menu using pseudo element
fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/phxzka6u/)

Comment: What is supposed to be there, if not a menu item name? Can you show an example of what you'd like the output to be?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do...how will people be able to use the menu if there's nothing within the link to click on?

Comment: I will use pseudo element to display the label i'll attached a fiddle on what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

When making the menu item add `&nbsp;` as the label and it will allow the field to be empty hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i understand your problem.
You can do it with using jQuery.
You have to add class to your particular menu in which you want to remove label.

> add this code to your header.php file

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.your-menu-class').find('a').html('');
  });
</script>
```

Don't remove page title from admin-side menu-setup.

Comment: sorry it was an error in this code i have update the code try it now.

Comment: i have great faith on jQuery try it again

Comment: i have fixed this issue by using just css visibility on the anchor and on the peasudo element. thanks anyway